# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of a object, while getting a label value using findcontrol which in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, label, findcontrol

Object reference not set to instance of an object, this error I'm getting when I click the linkbutton. The code bind file contain the below code for click event.

```
protected void viewProfileLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            String emailID = ((Label)ListView1.FindControl("profileTitleLabel")).Text;  
            Response.Redirect("profilePage.aspx?e=" + emailID);  
        }
```

My aspx page is like this:

```
default1.aspx: 

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
             <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </div>
                <div style=" text-align:right; margin-right:100px; width:750px;">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="2">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <hr  style=" float:left; width:552px; margin-left:17px;"/>
            <div class="center_title_bar" style="text-align:left;">
                    <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"first_name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_box_big">
            <div class="top_profile_box_big"></div>
            <div class="center_profile_box_big">          
                 <div class="profile_img_big">
                 &nbsp;<asp:Image ID="profileImage" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="150px" />
                 </div>
                     <div class="details_big_box">
                         <div class="specifications">
                            <asp:Label ID="profileTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"email_id") %>' 
                                 ForeColor="#388977"></asp:Label><br />

                         <asp:LinkButton ID="viewProfileLinkButton" runat="server">View Profile</asp:LinkButton>
                     </div>                        
            </div>
            <div class="bottom_profile_box_big"></div>
            </div>                        
        </div>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate/>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>

            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate/>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <br />
                <div class="center_title_bar" style="text-align:left;">
                    <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"first_name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_box_big">
            <div class="top_profile_box_big"></div>
            <div class="center_profile_box_big">          

                     <div class="details_big_box">
                         <div class="specifications">
                            <asp:Label ID="profileTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"email_id") %>' 
                                 ForeColor="#388977"></asp:Label><br />

                         </div>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="viewProfileLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="viewProfileLinkButton_Click">View Profile</asp:LinkButton>
                     </div>                        
            </div>
            <div class="bottom_profile_box_big"></div>
            </div>                        
        </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate/>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Please help me out, Thank you.....

Answer (score 1):

Your html has gone funny in the question so I cannot see where ListView1 is. I think it is safe to assume though that is is a ListView. In which case you cannot find your Label that way since it is in a ListViewItem rather than the ListView itself.

Something like `ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("profileTitleLabel");` is the thing you should be doing

Comment: that's great to hear... so usually the asker would upvote and best answer the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `FindControl` function could not find the target control because it is not directly contained in the `ListView`.